# No such file or directory when file exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bitcoin

I have a file called `bitcoind` in /usr/bin/bitcoind:

```
bitcoin@Titan:~$ ll /usr/bin | grep bitcoind
-rwxr-xr-x  1 bitcoin bitcoin 7789600 Nov 25 10:39 bitcoind*
```

However, I cannot execute it:

```
bitcoin@Titan:~$ bitcoind
-bash: /usr/bin/bitcoind: No such file or directory
```

`sudo` doesn't help:

```
bitcoin@Titan:~$ sudo bitcoind
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/bitcoind: No such file or directory
```

Found the suggestion that it's because it's missing some required libraries, so tried using 'ldd' to find them:

```
bitcoin@Titan:~$ ldd /usr/bin/bitcoin
ldd: /usr/bin/bitcoin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name doesn't contain any hidden characters? Verify with `ls /usr/bin | grep bitcoind | xxd`.

Comment: `0000000: 6269 7463 6f69 6e64 0a                   bitcoind.`

Comment: The `ldd` call misses a `d` at the end.

Comment: Can you provide the ouput of `file /usr/bin/bitcoind` and `uname -a`?

Comment: @choroba Corrected `ldd` call returns `not a dynamic executable`.

Comment: @chaos `file` returns `/usr/bin/bitcoind: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=41aded5bd1f93bef6c7972e3b0aa7f4c38098336, stripped`. `uname` returns `Linux Titan 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to run a 32-bit executable in a 64-bit system. That's not a problem, but you need some packages on your system to be able to do that.

Add the 32-bit architecture to the package library:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Update the package cache:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

After that you should be able to execute the 32 bit executable.

**A bit of background:**

`ldd` returns `not a dynamic executable` because it is not a 64 bit executable, hence not a 64 bit dynamic executable. To execute a 64 bit shaed object such as your executable, there must be a dynamic linker: [the linux loader](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux). Normally it resides in `/lib`. In 64-bit linux systems with a 32 bit linker there are two linker/loader: The 32-bit loader in `/lib32/ld-linux.so` and the 64-bit loader in `/lib64/ld-linux.so`. A 32-bit executable need 32-bit libraries, so your executable may need some more libraries. Install them in debian based systems with `apt-get install libxyz:i386`.